Flutter Gradle Build Fails: Namespace not specified for ':flutter_tflite'
I am encountering an issue while trying to build my Flutter project. The app fails to compile, and I receive the following error:
Error Message:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':flutter_tflite'.
> Could not create an instance of type com.android.build.api.variant.impl.LibraryVariantBuilderImpl.
   > Namespace not specified. Specify a namespace in the module's build file. See https://d.android.com/r/tools/upgrade-assistant/set-namespace for information about setting the namespace.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.

Environment Details:
Flutter version: 3.27.0
Dart version: 3.6.0
Android Studio version: 2024.2 (Artic Fox)
Gradle version: 8.3
Java version: OpenJDK 21

app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.ornek12flutter"
    compileSdkVersion 34
    ndkVersion = "25.1.8937393"

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }

    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'tflite'
        noCompress 'lite'
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = 17
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.ornek12flutter"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://flutter.dev/to/review-gradle-config.
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 34
        versionCode = flutter.versionCode
        versionName = flutter.versionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.7.20'
    repositories{
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies{
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.1.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <application
        android:label="ornek12flutter"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:taskAffinity=""
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <!-- Specifies an Android theme to apply to this Activity as soon as
                 the Android process has started. This theme is visible to the user
                 while the Flutter UI initializes. After that, this theme continues
                 to determine the Window background behind the Flutter UI. -->
            <meta-data
              android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.NormalTheme"
              android:resource="@style/NormalTheme"
              />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- Don't delete the meta-data below.
             This is used by the Flutter tool to generate GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="flutterEmbedding"
            android:value="2" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <!-- Required to query activities that can process text, see:
         https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility and
         https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#ACTION_PROCESS_TEXT.

         In particular, this is used by the Flutter engine in io.flutter.plugin.text.ProcessTextPlugin. -->
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PROCESS_TEXT"/>
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
        </intent>
    </queries>
</manifest>

android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.10.2-all.zip

settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.3.2" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "2.0.20" apply false
}

include ":app"

package:
get: ^4.6.6
camera: ^0.11.0+2
permission_handler: ^11.3.1
flutter_tflite: ^1.0.1

import 'dart:developer';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter_tflite/flutter_tflite.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

class ScanController extends GetxController{

  late CameraController cameraController;
  late List<CameraDescription> cameras;

  @override
  void onInit() async{
    super.onInit();

    initCamera();
    initTFLite();
  }

  @override
  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
    cameraController.dispose();
  }

  var isCameraInitialized = false.obs;
  var cameraCount = 0;

  var x,y,w,h = 0.0;
  var label = "";

  initCamera() async {
    if(await Permission.camera.request().isGranted){

      cameras = await availableCameras();
      cameraController =
          CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.max, imageFormatGroup: ImageFormatGroup.yuv420);
      await cameraController.initialize().then((value){
        cameraController.startImageStream((image) {
          cameraCount ++;
          if(cameraCount % 10 == 0){
            cameraCount = 0;
            objectDetector(image);
          }
          update();
        } );
      });
      isCameraInitialized(true);
      update();
    }else{
      print("Permission denied");
    }
  }

  initTFLite() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(
      model: "assets/detect.tflite",
      labels: "assets/label.txt",
      isAsset: true,
      numThreads: 1,
      useGpuDelegate: false,
    );
  }

  objectDetector(CameraImage image) async {
    var detector = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
      bytesList: image.planes.map((e){
        return e.bytes;
      }).toList(),
      asynch: true,
      imageHeight: image.height,
      imageWidth: image.width,
      imageMean: 127.5,
      imageStd: 127.5,
      rotation: 90,
      threshold: 0.4,
    );

    if(detector != null){
      var ourDetectedObject = detector.first;
      if(ourDetectedObject['confidenceInClass'] * 100 > 45){
        label = detector.first['detectedClass'].toString();
        h = ourDetectedObject['rect']['h'];
        w = ourDetectedObject['rect']['w'];
        x = ourDetectedObject['rect']['x'];
        y = ourDetectedObject['rect']['y'];
      }
      update();
    }
  }
}

import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';
import 'package:ornek12flutter/scan.dart';

class CameraView extends StatelessWidget {
  const CameraView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GetBuilder<ScanController>(
          init: ScanController(),
          builder: (controller) {
            return controller.isCameraInitialized.value
                ? Stack(
              children: [
                CameraPreview(controller.cameraController),
                Positioned(
                  top: controller.y * 700,
                  right: controller.x * 500,
                  child: Container(
                    width: controller.w * 100 * context.width / 100,
                    height: controller.h * 100 * context.height / 100,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      border: Border.all(color: Colors.green, width: 4.0),
                    ),
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Text(controller.label),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
                : const Center(child: Text("Loading Preview..."));
          }),
    );
  }
}

Upgraded the Gradle version to 8.3 in the gradle-wrapper.properties file, but it didn’t resolve the problem.
Verified the Java version (OpenJDK 21) and ensured compatibility with Gradle.
Searched online for solutions and reviewed documentation but couldn’t find a clear way to resolve the issue.
What were you expecting?
I expected my project to build and run successfully without any errors.

The flutter_tflite package was last released two years ago, which probably means the package's author(s) may have not added support for the namespace requirement when using a Gradle version above 8.
You could either:

Downgrade your Gradle version to be below 8
Ask the owner(s) of flutter_tflite to add the necessary support (but I don't know if anyone is going to do that following the fact that it hasn't been updated in so long)
Use a different library that suits your needs (I noticed there is a package called tflite_flutter, which seems to be more recently updated)

